# Noob here: I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind this regular expression search

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm having trouble understanding the logic in the regular expression inside the preg_replace function.  Specifically, I'm having trouble understanding the use of the caret inside the brackets.  If I type a single letter/number that matches any letter/number in the username column, I'll get a match for that row.  When I remove the caret, even when I don't search for anything, everything in my db matches.  Can someone please elaborate on what's going on here?  Thanks.

```
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z]/i","",$searchq );

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM people ".
"WHERE username LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die('Could not search.');
```

Comment: @nogad: no, wrong. it's in side a `[]` character class, it's a NEGATION operator

Comment: ........Doh :-)

Answer (score 3):

`[^0-9a-z]` is a character class (`[]`). `^` in a character class is negation, aka "not", so literally it's saying "match anything that is NOT a digit or an alphabetical character.

Answer (score 2):

In basically every regex flavour, the square brackets `[]` denote a *character class*, which will match one instance of any character in it. A character class starting with a caret `^` is *negated* - i.e. it will match a single instance of any character that is *not* in it.

In this case, your character class will match any character that isn't a number or lowercase letter. Because your regex is in ignore-case mode (the `i` modifier), it'll match any character that isn't a number or ASCII letter (either upper or lowercase), and the `preg_replace` will strip it out by replacing it with the empty string (`""`).